# listing onedrive item permissions return obscure data

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, onedrive

As long as I still haven't found a working solution to get Sharepoint Online site permissions through microsoft graph api (which returns 200 OK and an empty array), I am trying to get permissions for the onedrive resource bound to this site.
According to the manual
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
I am trying to get onedrive item permissions for the item located on the site MYSITE using a query like this:

`GET /drives/somedriveid/items/someitemid/permissions`

The result contains data which I cannot understand:

```
[{'id': 'cm9kaW4gT3duZXJz',
  'roles': ['owner'],
  'grantedToV2': {'siteGroup': {'displayName': 'MYSITE Owners',
    'id': '3',
    'loginName': 'MYSITE Owners'}},
  'grantedTo': {'user': {'displayName': 'MYSITE Owners'}},
  'inheritedFrom': {}},
 {'id': 'cm9kaW4gVmlzaXRvcnM',
  'roles': ['read'],
  'grantedToV2': {'siteGroup': {'displayName': 'MYSITE Visitors',
    'id': '4',
    'loginName': 'MYSITE Visitors'}},
  'grantedTo': {'user': {'displayName': 'MYSITE Visitors'}},
  'inheritedFrom': {}},
 {'id': 'cm9kaW4gTWVtYmVycw',
  'roles': ['write'],
  'grantedToV2': {'siteGroup': {'displayName': 'MYSITE Members',
    'id': '5',
    'loginName': 'MYSITE Members'}},
  'grantedTo': {'user': {'displayName': 'MYSITE Members'}},
  'inheritedFrom': {}},
 {'id': 'aTowIy5mfG1lbWJlcnNoaXB8bS5yb2RpbkB0ZWFtLXNlcnZpY2UucnU',
  'roles': ['owner'],
  'grantedToV2': {'user': {'@odata.type': '#microsoft.graph.sharePointIdentity',
    'displayName': 'My Real User Name',
    'email': 'myrealusername@somedomain.dom',
    'id': '08278fd9-dfe5-4c3b-a38e-08f06da2f59b'},
   'siteUser': {'displayName': 'My Real User Name',
    'email': 'myrealusername@somedomain.dom',
    'id': '6',
    'loginName': 'i:0#.f|membership|myrealusername@somedomain.dom'}},
  'grantedTo': {'user': {'displayName': 'My Real User Name',
    'email': 'myrealusername@somedomain.dom',
    'id': '08278fd9-dfe5-4c3b-a38e-08f06da2f59b'}},
  'inheritedFrom': {}}]
```

The only valid user returned by the query is me (I am the creator and the owner).
The other site visitors which I added seem to hide behind the groups 'MYSITE Owners', 'MYSITE Visitors' and 'MYSITE Members'.
How can reveal the contents of these site specific groups?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggeling with this issue as well. Currently, the Graph API does not support such functionality and we have to use the SharePoint REST API to get these users.

Useful links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints
- https://sharepointcass.com/2021/04/15/sharepoint-online-rest-apis-part-v-sharepoint-groups/